# How to Add Image/Shape with chart data label in ASPOSE Slide

Tags: aspose, aspose-slides

Can we add any shape/image with chart data labels in ASPOSE .I need to show one arrow with different colors according to certain values with each data labels in the chart. i am using ASPOSE to generate my ppt. Or there is any way to find the data label positions in ASPOSE.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have observed your requirements and like to share that MS PowerPoint supports LineWithMarker chart that can display different predefined or custom marker symbols(in the form of image) for different series data points. Please try using following sample code for possible options using Aspose.Slides and MSO charts.

```
public static void TestScatter()
{
    var location = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

    //Open a presentation
    Presentation pres = new Presentation();
    IChart chart = pres.Slides[0].Shapes.AddChart(ChartType.StackedLineWithMarkers, 10, 10, 400, 400);
    //populating cycle
    var serie = chart.ChartData.Series[0];
    var wbk = chart.ChartData.ChartDataWorkbook;
    chart.ChartData.Series.RemoveAt(1);
    chart.ChartData.Series.RemoveAt(1);

    serie.Marker.Format.Fill.FillType = FillType.Picture;
    serie.Marker.Size = 20;

    // Set the picture
    System.Drawing.Image img = (System.Drawing.Image)new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Tulips.jpg");
    IPPImage imgx = pres.Images.AddImage(img);
    serie.Marker.Format.Fill.PictureFillFormat.Picture.Image = imgx;

    //For individual data point
    serie.DataPoints[0].Marker.Format.Fill.FillType = FillType.Solid;
    serie.DataPoints[0].Marker.Format.Fill.SolidFillColor.Color = Color.Red;
    serie.DataPoints[0].Marker.Size = 20;
    serie.DataPoints[0].Marker.Symbol = MarkerStyleType.Triangle;

    serie.DataPoints[0].Label.DataLabelFormat.ShowValue = true;
    serie.DataPoints[1].Label.DataLabelFormat.ShowValue = true;
    serie.DataPoints[2].Label.DataLabelFormat.ShowValue = true;
    serie.DataPoints[3].Label.DataLabelFormat.ShowValue = true;

    pres.Save(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(location), "Result2.pptx"), SaveFormat.Pptx);

}
```

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Many Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for your support,but i need that symbol with data labels not in marker.in above figure i showed that symbol with data labels only that i positioned right of the marker.If i go with marker can i able to make the design exactly like this???

Comment: I replaced the image with markers(please check above image).According to above solution if i change marker and put image the position will be wrong.after how i will change the position of the marker???

Comment: i need both marker(in diamond) and data labels  so if we edit marker then the required design will go wrong

Answer (score 1):

I have further observed your requirements and have observed that you have also posted the similar requirements in [Aspose.Slides official support forum](https://forums.aspose.com/t/how-to-add-image-shape-with-chart-data-label-in-slide/501) as well. Please try using following sample code on your end to serve the purpose.

```
public static void TestLineChart()
{
var location = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

//Open a presentation
Presentation pres = new Presentation();
IChart chart = pres.Slides[0].Shapes.AddChart(ChartType.StackedLineWithMarkers, 10, 10, 400, 400);
//populating cycle
var serie = chart.ChartData.Series[0];
var wbk = chart.ChartData.ChartDataWorkbook;
chart.ChartData.Series.RemoveAt(1);
chart.ChartData.Series.RemoveAt(1);

serie.Marker.Format.Fill.FillType = FillType.Picture;
serie.Marker.Size = 20;


serie.Marker.Symbol = MarkerStyleType.Diamond;
serie.Marker.Format.Fill.FillType = FillType.Solid;
serie.Marker.Format.Fill.SolidFillColor.Color=Color.Orange;
serie.Marker.Format.Line.FillFormat.FillType = FillType.Solid;
serie.Marker.Format.Line.FillFormat.SolidFillColor.Color=Color.Red;
serie.Marker.Format.Line.Width=1.0F;

serie.Format.Line.Width = 3.0f;
serie.Format.Line.FillFormat.FillType=FillType.Solid;
serie.Format.Line.FillFormat.SolidFillColor.Color = Color.FromArgb(209,225,91) ;

for(int i=0;i<serie.DataPoints.Count;i++)
{
serie.DataPoints[i].Label.DataLabelFormat.ShowValue = true;
    IDataLabel label=serie.Labels[i];
    chart.ValidateChartLayout();
    IAutoShape ashp=chart.UserShapes.Shapes.AddAutoShape(ShapeType.Triangle,chart.X + label.ActualX + 5, chart.Y + label.ActualY + 5, 20,20);
    ashp.FillFormat.FillType = FillType.Solid;

    ashp.LineFormat.FillFormat.FillType = FillType.NoFill;
    if (i % 2 == 0)//even data points
    {
        ashp.FillFormat.SolidFillColor.Color = Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        ashp.Rotation = 180;
        ashp.FillFormat.SolidFillColor.Color = Color.Red;
    }
}

pres.Save(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(location), "Result2.pptx"), Aspose.Slides.Export.SaveFormat.Pptx);

}
```

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Many Thanks,

Comment: when i tried to implement this code i am getting 2 issues
1. Chart.X and label.X is coming as NaN(instead of ActualX i used X)
2. ActualX is not coming in Label properties

whether the second issue is related to ASPOSE version?